# Why can I not iterate my model in my template?

Tags: ember.js

I've been recently playing with Ember.js utilizing Ember CLI and I am running into an issue with a very simple application I cannot seem to get around.

I have set up an Ember Data fixture adapter with a simple model "Post" which contains two string properties--title & content.  I've then proceeded to map a route like so:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', {path: '/'});
});
```

Then create a router for posts which simply returns the model data:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.store.find('post');
  }
});
```

My template simply iterates through all the posts in the model like so:

```
{{#each post in model}}
    <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{post.content}}</h3>
{{/each}}
```

The Ember browser extension properly shows my two test posts in the Data tab like so:

[image: Ember browser extension data tab]

But for some reason the template simply will not render the model data.  My application.hbs file does contain the appropriate {{outlet}} which I've tested by adding some dummy text into the post.hbs file.  This text shows up properly.

Any idea why my model will not display properly would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot access this behind my work firewall.  I will post it there later on today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you made an error while typing your code into StackOverflow, your issue is that you're not actually returning anything in your model hook. Change this:

```
 this.store.find('post');
```

To this:

```
 return this.store.find('post');
```

Comment: Oh Lord....doh!  I was beating my head against the wall trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.  Thank you so much!